# Different Style for each result

Tags: php

I try show all the hours of the day in order 8, 9, 10 ... but to distinguish the hours that are in the database from the hours that are not. For instance, to give a different color. Can anyone help? (I am not a programmer and I am just learning php alone, so any I would appreciate any help, but explain it in a simple way, please)

This gives me the hours that I have in the database in blue. But I cannot to get hours that are not in the database and I cannot give them another color and the right position: 8, 9,10, 11...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM consulta
                  WHERE professional=1
                  AND client=0');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($row['hour']=='09:00:00') { echo '<p style="color:blue;">9</p>'; } 
elseif ($row['hour']=='10:00:00')  { echo '<p style="color:blue;">10</p>'; } 
elseif ($row['hour']=='11:00:00')  { echo '<p style="color:blue;">11</p>'; } 
elseif ($row['hour']=='12:00:00')  { echo '<p style="color:blue;">12</p>'; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sudo code for you. Make an array with all the hours in it. Then iterate that array instead of the result from the database.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
    if(in_array("$i:00:00", $row)) {
        // hour was found in the database
        echo '<p style="color:blue;">'.$i.'</p>';
    } else {
        // hour was not found
        echo '<p style="color:red;">'.$i.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said, I am just a beginner. I do not understand your code. Can you explain it or make it more simple?

Comment: @Shomz iteration is a bit better. I edited my code. So what this does is iterate 24 times. For each iteration the varible $i counts up.. Then in the "if" we ask by using in_array if the value "$i:00:00" is in the array $row from the database. $row contains your hours from the database. If we find it then we know that its in the database and you can color one way. If not its not in the database and you go into the else. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: this gives 0 1 2...23 but 3 times. The first time all red, second time 1 value of the database in blue, third time the other value of the database in blue. I do not understand?

Comment: Sorry there was a syntax error at $++ should be $i++. I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

This way you're iterating over hours that **are** in the database. Just them. So if 11 is not in the database, if simply won't show. You need a different logic.

You need to iterate over all 24 hours and for each hour check if it is in the database, if so, apply styling, if not, render normally. And a hint, it might be easier to defince CSS classes instead of using inline styling (`<p class="db">9</p>` instead of `<p style="color:blue;">9</p>`, and of course, having the `db` class defined properly; that way you only need to change one rule instead of styling of each element in case you want to change something).

Comment: thank you @Shomz. Your advise about the class is very good. I tried and it works. In relation of the other point I do not know how to iterate over all 24 hours. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: You're welcome. 24 hours could be a simple for loop: `for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $++) {`... and then inside you can build your hour string to compare with like this: `$hour = "$i:00:00";` and then you just to compare it with all rows and check `if ($row['hour'] == $hour)`...